# dynamic table in jsp file

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxlnc.png)

I need to create this table in my project by using spring mvc and javascript in my jsp file how can I do this? I want to get the month from date in this form 
"yyyy-MM-dd" can you help me?

Comment: can you please add some code, what you have tried?

Comment: do you see the picture that I post?

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse a Date into a certain format you do the following.

BEWARE: THIS SOLUTION IS A CHEAP ONE

```
String[] date_s = {"02-24-1994","04-24-1999","01-13-2014"};
StringBuilder table= new StringBuilder("<table><tbody>");
for(int i=0;i<date_s.length;i++){
     SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy");
     Date date = dt.parse(date_s[i]);
     SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
     table.append("<tr><td>").append(dt1.format(date)).append("</td></tr>");
}
table.append("</tbody></table>");
```

It should produce the right format, then you can store this as a variable and send it to JSP

```
PrintWriter res = response.getWriter();
res.print(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Java Standard Tag library to format date into any of the format.

Refer this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm

Answer (score 0):

it may helps , for custom date format in JSP's we can use formatting tag . by using this tag we can format messages, numbers and date etc. for taht we need to add this syntax to our jsp - **<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"  %>**

first we need to set date :
`<c:set var="Date" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />`

later you can generate your date pattern by using pattern attribute of formating tag. 
    `<fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" value = "${Date}" />`

**need to add jars**:
JSTL jars are container specific, for example in Tomcat, we need to include jstl.jar and standard.jar jar files in project build path. If they are not present in the container lib directory, you should include them into your application.

in JSP Page we can create dynamic table by using core tags.

```
<table>
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="listObj">
   <tr>
     <td><c:out value="${listObj.val1}" /></td>
     <td><c:out value="${listObj.val2}" /></td>
     <td><fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" value = "${Date}" /></td>
   </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

creating dynamic table using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var date = ${Date} // we get this from jsp SET Attribute.
function generateDynamicTable()
{
var listObj = '';
 var htm = "";
 htm = "<table>";
 for (var i = 0; i < giveListSize; i ++)
{
   listObj = list[i];
  htm += "<tr>";
  htm += "<td>" + listObj.val1 + "</td>";
  htm += "<td>" + listObj.val2 + "</td>";
  htm += "<td> <fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" value = "'+date+'" /> </td>";
  htm += "</tr>";
}
htm += "</table>";
document.write(htm);
} 
</scipt>
```

if it helps please promote.